# The natural numbers are a infinite union of disjoint countably infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I know this question and similar questions are posted with many examples, but I can't find my solution anywhere. I thought my solution was pretty obvious and so I am thinking I have done something wrong. Can you help me find the error in my ways?

Let $A_i= \{2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}...p_i^{n_i} \ \mid n_1,n_2,n_3,...,n_{i-1}\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} , n_i\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Obviously each $A_i$ is infinite. w.l.o.g suppose $a\in A_i\cap A_j$ where $i< j$. Since $a\in A_j$, it must contain a non zero power of $p_j$ in its prime factorization, but no element of $A_i$ has a non zero power of $p_j$ in its prime factorization. Every natural numbers shows up in some $A_i$ and we are done.

edit* as pointed out below, I will add $1$ to $A_1$

Comment: Rephrased, you have partitioned the natural numbers into sets according to the largest prime dividing each number in the set.  This is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Typo: it must be $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There are uncountably many ways to partition the natural numbers into infinitely many infinite sets. If we put all of them on the site, I think the internet will explode.

Comment: Valid point, but again it was the fist thing I thought of and I am usually not that quick (let's not lie...never that quick), so I assumed I was missing something silly :) Thanks everyone.

Comment: looks like we might get a few more examples anyway lol

Comment: Before logging off tmpys, @PatrickStevens does bring up a valid point in his answer, you will need to modify your answer slightly to account for the number $1$ which currently appears in none of your sets (*or appears alone in $A_0$*) by manually adding it in to one of the other sets as a special case.

Comment: ahh right, I added that to the first set in my notes but forgot to add.

Comment: Just because it is an interesting and surprising actual use of such a decomposition (in the guise of an ordering of the natural numbers) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're fine.

Simpler phrasing which defines essentially the same sets: let $A_i$ be the set of numbers which have exactly $i$ prime factors, and additionally put $1$ into $A_1$ (and, depending on your persuasion, put $0 \in A_1$ if $0$ is a natural number).

Another example: define the set $A_i$ to be the natural numbers with $i$ instances of $1$ in their binary expansion. (Here, $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$.)

Comment: "*simpler phrasing which defines essentially the same sets... which have exactly $i$ prime factors*"  Although this is another valid example, it does not define the same sets.  The number $25$ has only one prime factor and would for instance appear in your $A_1$ but it would appear in the OP's $A_3$ as it's largest prime factor is the *third* prime number.

Comment: $3$ is in $A_2$ because $2^03^1$ is in $A_2$

Comment: @tmpys Ah, I misread your $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$ as $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: nah you were right, it said n_1 but it was a typo. Fixed now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: But I forgot about 1.

Comment: $0$ a natural number???? what am I a lunatic? jk

Comment: @tmpys: Apparently you don't think that a set is finite if and only if its cardinal number is a natural number. So you are a lunatic, yes. :)

Comment: :) touche my friend

Comment: And also $\mathbb{N}$ is not a monoid under addition, but it is a monoid under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Indirect proof: is know that there is a bijection $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb N$. Take
$$A_n = \{f(m,n):m\in\Bbb N\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As you were told by others, what you did is more or less fine.

A different solution would be: if $A_0$ is the set of all odd natural numbers and if, for $n\in\mathbb N$,$$A_n=\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}\,\middle|\,2^n\mid k\wedge2^{n+1}\nmid k\right\},$$then each $a_n$ is countable and their union is a disjoint union. Furthermore, the union of all $A_n$'s is $\mathbb N$.